# Add playlist to iframe tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

My application have playlist for playing those videos I am using

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="video-container">
        <iframe width="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{{ media.src }}" frameborder="0 " allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

so now how to add playlist videos into this.

Answer (score 1):

src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL55713C70BA91BD6E" frameborder="0"

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgpdm8ur/)

in your case  `media.src="videoseries?list=PL55713C70BA91BD6E"`

**Update:**

You can create your own playlist using IFrame Player API:

Below is an example, witch does't run on stack overflow, copy paste the code in a local html file and open it in your browser.

```
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            videoId: 'f4Mc-NYPHaQ',//start videos id's
            playerVars: {
                color: 'white',
                playlist: 'YR5ApYxkU-U,Tj75Arhq5ho'//next videos in playlist
            }
  });
```

index.html next

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            videoId: 'f4Mc-NYPHaQ',
            playerVars: {
                color: 'white',
                playlist: 'YR5ApYxkU-U,Tj75Arhq5ho'
            },
            events: {
              'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Suppose I have three videos with comma separated url, so how to append. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNRsvFsY9qk,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dulxbKkj9Wg

Comment: You can't, you will need to write your own playlist, using same frame and changing the source or create the playlist with https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists

Comment: without creating own playlist, is it possible with any other dependency?